# Correct method to create python raw socket

Tags: python

I was reading some information security and programming stuff recently and I came across raw socket. I am kind of confused for a way to create raw socket and capture the packet correctly.

#### Method 1

create socket with `AF_INET`

```
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.IPPROTO_*)

##IPPROTO_* can be IPPROTO_IP/IPPROTO_TCP/IPPROTO_UDP

raw_data=sock.recvfrom(65535)
```

But using this method I'm able to capture the packet but when i tried to decode it, I am not able to making any sense.

#### Method 2

```
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.htons(0x0800))

raw_data=socket.recvfrom(65535)
```

by using second method I'm able to capture as well as decode it.

FYI, I'm trying to decode packet from ethernet lavel.

So my question is why method I is failing? and Is there anyother way to create raw socket in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create protocolless raw socket, use: `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)`;

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from socket import socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW
s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
s.bind(("eth1", 0))

# We're putting together an ethernet frame here, 
# but you could have anything you want instead
# Have a look at the 'struct' module for more 
# flexible packing/unpacking of binary data
# and 'binascii' for 32 bit CRC
src_addr = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06"
dst_addr = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06"
payload = ("["*30)+"PAYLOAD"+("]"*30)
checksum = "\x1a\x2b\x3c\x4d"
ethertype = "\x08\x01"

s.send(dst_addr+src_addr+ethertype+payload+checksum)
```

All credits to [brice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140264/brice)

Comment: I have refer this question but what is differance between two method i specified.

Comment: while using AF_PACKET third argument to socket fuction should be protocol number in network byte order.

Comment: But setting protocol = not raw socket communication. Raw means, you write your packets by or own, not some protocol wrapper. You can still bind it to interface though.

Comment: Not true.  Setting a protocol means that `s.recv` will only receive packets with that protocol number.  You still have to construct and parse the whole frame, including smac/dmac/ethertype, yourself.

Comment: @Tom not true? you just repeated what I said. Read with understanding before claiming that someone says something that is not true.

Comment: You said "setting protocol = not raw socket communication".  This is absolutely not true.  You still write your packets on your own and you get no protocol wrapper.

Comment: THAT is not true. You don't have to build the whole frame when using a defined protocol. Maybe you are just misunderstanding the "frame". You probably should read something about protocols and frames, and what is not the part of defining the packet in given protocols (as it's a part of the protocol itself). Maybe something about sniffing as well, and why to use RAW socket im these cases.

Comment: Suggest you go and read the documentation for `socket`.  Or try it and see for yourself; run the above code with `tcpdump -e` running, then add a protocol number to the `socket` call and see if the tcpdump output changes (hint: it doesn't).

Comment: Now I suggest you read the documentation for `tcpdump` and see what the `-e` option does.

Comment: To quote `man tcpdump`: `-e   Print  the link-level header on each dump line.  This can be used, for example, to print MAC layer addresses for protocols such as Ethernet and IEEE 802.11.`

Comment: link-level is not the whole frame, would suggest to read something about network infrastructure

Comment: For instance `18:06:55.342927 d4:25:cc:b0:25:21 (oui Unknown) > 00:e0:4c:68:0a:c0 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 226: fe80::d625:ccff:feb0:2521.ssh > fe80::b068:5fde:a15e:cd01.38796: Flags [P.], seq 1945944086:1945944226, ack 523928708, win 1459, options [nop,nop,TS val 50293500 ecr 401431276], length 140`, to pick a random frame off my network.  Clearly showing the fields from the Ethernet frame header.  Now would you like to try the experiment I suggested?  What fields do you think you're filling in in the code in your answer that are outside the link-level fields?